# Does MiA1 support Rescue Party?

Tags: adb, 8.0-oreo, mi-a1

I wanted to check if [Rescue Party](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/rescue-party), a much touted feature of Oreo is active on my device ( since it is not mandated in Android Compatibility Definition Document as the linked source says)

The first step is to override USB connection (suppression) , since

> All rescue events are suppressed when the device has an active USB data connection because that's a strong signal that someone is debugging the device

To do that  run

`adb shell setprop persist.sys.enable_rescue 1`

My device returns

`setprop: failed to set property 'persist.sys.enable_rescue' to '1'`

**Can I conclude from this that Mi A1 doesn't support Rescue Party?**
 ( some explanation would help)

Aside, this XDA thread [No, Android Oreo’s Rescue Party is not the bootloop fix you were looking for](https://www.xda-developers.com/no-android-oreo-rescue-party-not-bootloop-fix/) gives useful details on Rescue Party ( Please note that my device is **not** rooted )